# Accessing Cronjob Log files on AWS EC2 instance

Tags: python, cron, amazon-ec2, logging

I would like to start by expressing my appreciation to any help I receive. I am very new to AWS and ubuntu servers.

I run a daily python job on my EC2 instance and it fails every Friday for some reason. I essentially want the python error code that is spat out when the code breaks, if I was running it in the terminal or ssh.

I have looked in var/log/syslog and cant find what im looking for, been searching for the answer for over a week now and decided to write here.

Thanks for taking the time to help

Comment: There's likely to be little information logged beyond that cron attempted to run the command - if you want more, redirect your cronjob's error and/or output streams to a log file of your choosing

Comment: thanks for your reply SteelDriver - I ended up writing a logging module in the python code to track it, not the cleanest solution but one that will work for now

Answer (score 2):

Wrap your python3 script in a `bash` script, and invoke that script from your `crontab`. Suggested script:

```
#!/bin/bash
logfile="/tmp/my.log"
echo "$(date) ============ begin" >>"$logfile"
who >>"$logfile"
ps  >>"$logfile"
df >>"$logfile"
# other commands to investigate the environment >>"$logfile"
# ...
# your python command goes here. The `&>>` redirects STDOUT and STDERR. 
python ...  &>>"$logfile"
status=$? 
echo "$(date) exit status: $status"  >>"$logfile"
exit $status
```

That will get you started.